# Program stops working with too many files in array

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, sigabrt

I have written this search program for searching through an array of objects which contains a file name and a pathway to the file on my computer. When I wrote the program, I had two test files which worked great with my code. I then started adding the actual files and it worked fine with 10-20 files, so I decided to add a few more (about 45 which made a grand total of around 60 files). This is were it goes wrong; The program runs, but I can't search for any file without getting the "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error, on the line were my search function is. I also get an error message in the console but I'm afraid that I can't understand it. It doesn't matter if the file is searchable when I only have 10 files, it stops working when I use all of them. I include my code below:

SMADoc.h (custom class for creating the objects that are PDF's)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SMADoc : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *docNumber
@property (nonatomic) NSString *urlToDoc;

@end
```

main.m (with 5 of the files)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SMADoc.h"
#include <readline/readline.h>
@import AppKit;

void *documentSearch() {
SMADoc *one = [[SMADoc alloc] init];
[one setdocNumber:@(17800)];
[one setUrlToDoc:@"/Users/Docs/docPath1.pdf"];

SMADoc *two = [[SMADoc alloc] init];
[two setdocNumber:@(11632)];
[two setUrlToDoc:@"/Users/Docs/docPath2.pdf"];

SMADoc *three = [[SMADoc alloc] init];
[three setdocNumber:@(17583)];
[three setUrlToDoc:@"/Users/Docs/docPath3.pdf"];

SMADoc *four = [[SMADoc alloc] init];
[four setdocNumber:@(14351)];
[four setUrlToDoc:@"/Users/Docs/docPath4.pdf"];

SMADoc *five = [[SMADoc alloc] init];
[five setdocNumber:@(11628)];
[five setUrlToDoc:@"/Users/Docs/docPath5.pdf"];

NSMutableArray *docs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:one, two, three, four, five, nil];

int i = 0;

NSLog(@"Enter what you want to search for: ");
const char *searchC = readline(NULL);
int number = atoi(searchC);
NSNumber *sNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:number];

for (SMADoc *nSearch in docs) {
    if ([sNumber isEqualToNumber:[nSearch docNumber]]) {
        NSLog(@"Opening document...");
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:[nSearch urlToDoc]];
    }
    if (![sNumber isEqualToNumber:[nSearch docNumber]]) {
        i++;
    }
}
if (i == [docs count]) {
    NSLog(@"A match could not be found, please check your spelling");
}
free(documentSearch());
documentSearch();

return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    NSLog(@"message");
    documentSearch();
}
return 0;
}
```

And it is this line below that gets the SIGABRT-error:

```
 if ([sNumber isEqualToNumber:[nSearch docNumber]]) {
```

And this is the output in the console:

```
2015-07-09 14:28:25.047 LIX4[3537:108937] message
2015-07-09 14:28:25.049 LIX4[3537:108937] Enter what you want to search   for: 
1177880000

2015-07-09 14:28:27.505 LIX4[3537:108937] Opening document...
2015-07-09 14:28:27.633 LIX4[3537:108937] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-07-09 14:28:27.633 LIX4[3537:108937] -[__NSCFNumber compare:]: nil argument
2015-07-09 14:28:27.633 LIX4[3537:108937] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b8ae03c     __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ef9076e     objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b8adeed +    [NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b7ab031 -    [__NSCFNumber compare:] + 81
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b7aafc8 -    [__NSCFNumber isEqualToNumber:] + 24
    5   LIX4                                0x0000000100004a3a     documentSearch + 14490
    6   LIX4                                0x0000000100005355 main + 53   
    7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8fb6f5c9 start + 1
)
2015-07-09 14:28:27.634 LIX4[3537:108937] *** Terminating app due to   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber     compare:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b8ae03c     __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ef9076e     objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b8adeed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b7ab031 -[__NSCFNumber compare:] + 81
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b7aafc8 -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToNumber:] + 24
    5   LIX4                                0x0000000100004a3a     documentSearch + 14490
    6   LIX4                                0x0000000100005355 main + 53
    7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8fb6f5c9 start + 1
)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type     NSException
    (lldb)
```

If anyone could help me figure this out I would be very grateful!

Comment: It doesn't look like you've posted the code where the error is actually happening: the line you quoted (with the call to `-LIX_number`) doesn't appear.

Comment: the error message says that NSNumber is compared with a nil value which causes the exception. What is `LIX_number`?

Comment: Whoops, wrong line, my bad

Comment: This may not be related to your issue, but what is the point of `free(documentSearch());
documentSearch();`? If I am not much mistaken then you create an endless recursion here as soon as you get rid of the `SIGABRT`.

Comment: Does it make a change when you use `setDocNumber` instead of `setdocNumber`?

Comment: @HermannKlecker I might be wrong on this, but my thought was that it would deallocate all the variables and objects in the function so that those wouldn't stack up when calling the function again. Yes, it will be endless, so that when you have searched for a document the function will start over and you are able to search for another document right away without restarting the program. What you are suggesting sounds like a solution, but the thing is that it works when I run it with 10 files... But thanks for your comment!

Comment: @HermannKlecker No, unfortunately it does not.

Comment: No, that is not going to happen. You can call free on a pointer that points to some earlier allocated memory when used with malloc. But you cannot call free on the returnvalue of a function (unless the function returns exaclty a pointer to the memory that is to be freed.) 
Your function returns 0. You would therfore try to free nil, of which I don't know what happens then. However, you did not use malloc. You alloc Objective-C objects which are released not freed. Ad they are released only when you do not ARC. With ARC the ARC will release them.

Comment: (cont...) But it is even worse. You call the same function within the parameter list of free. So the function will be invoked again. Nearly at its end it will call the function again in the parameter list of free. And that repeats over an over.

Comment: (cont ...) It is even worse than that. As you call your function within your function none of these functions will ever return. You just push the new function with its new local variables on the stack again and again and never pull them. The result will be the name of the forum a stackoverflow error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! The people over at MacRumors helped me solve my problem! I opened up both versions of my program; The one with 60 files that kept crashing and the one with five files (the code I posted here) and set a breakpoint at

```
if ([sNumber isEqualToNumber:[nSearch docNumber]])
```

in both versions and then examined the variables and I found something that was wrong. I turned out that the value of the `sNumber` variable, which is what the user puts in, sometimes got stored in a `double` instead of a `int` and this was the problem! I solved this by using the variable number instead of sNumber (since that already was a int) and replacing this code:

```
if ([sNumber isEqualToNumber:[nSearch docNumber]]) {

    [...]

if (![sNumber isEqualToNumber:[nSearch docNumber]]) {
```

with this:

```
if (number == [[nSearch docNumber] intValue]) {

    [...]


(!(number == [[nSearch docNumber] intValue])) {
```

And that solved the problem!

EDIT: Here is a link to the MacRumors-thread if anyone is interested: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/comparing-two-numbers-causes-error.1900677/

Answer (score 0):

have your object contains number ? , I am feeling

```
[nSearch docNumber]
```

must be nil, i.e it's crashing

Comment: I, too, think that `[nSearch docNumber]` returns nil for some reason. But why? `nSearc` is the iterating object over all objects within `docs` and you can clearly see that `docs` contains 5 elements of type `SMADoc` and you can see how they are created.

Comment: @HermannKlecker

can you please define your property as 

**@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *docNumber;**

and try.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I tried it, but unfortunately I still get the same error on the same line and the same output in the console.

Comment: can you please print your array object before for loop ? and let us know.

Comment: (It is not my code :-) ) As he does not hit the end of an @autoreleasepool block, a strong or weak reference does not matter too mutch. Although you are right, it should be a strong one.

Comment: @AngelVasa Sorry for the delay! I got a value for each number when printing them out, here is the output: `1: 17800
2: 11632
3: 17583
4: 14351
5: 11628
6: 11629
7: 12077
8: 16982
9: 16983
10: 11002
11: 13846
12: 17762
13: 11626
14: 13138
15: 13451
16: 15640
17: 13138
18: 11631
19: 10802
20: 10991
Program ended with exit code: 0`
(minus the timestamp, that took up too much space) and here is the code I used to print it:
`int i = 0;
    
    for (SMADoc *numberDoc in docs) {
        i++;
        NSLog(@"%i: %@", i, [numberDoc docNumber]);
    }`

Comment: That looks ok... What about sNumber. Can you print that. Most probably it's nil

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but referring to our conversation in comments regarding the endless loop. Yours is recursive and will never end. By time you will run into a stackoverflow. 
This is a proper way of achieving the same:

```
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    while (true) {
      @autoreleasepool {
        documentSearch();
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `@autoreleasepool` is within the loop.